# gatsby + netlify cms images not loading

Tags: image, gatsby, netlify-cms

I followed the steps to create a gatsby site with netlify cms https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-blog-with-gatsby-and-netlify-cms/. However when I upload a blog post with images in it, **the images do not display on page**

As per the config.yml changes, the `images/uploads` folder gets added to a folder `images/uploads` as a sibling to `content/blog` folder.

[image: config file changes]

On the page, the image does not load and throws the 404 error. I upload the image via netlify cms admin portal and the image url gets generated automatically and via the netlify cms admin portal images displays fine(but as a blob). How do I get the images to display on the final page here https://blogs.neelamegam.in/2024-03-24-another-day-another-image/

[image: image not loading]

Comment: Seems like the guide you've followed missing the part of how gatsby handles the images. Take a look on gatsby docs https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings I had worked. I think it took some time to reflect and I had to look at a different blog post to see the image uploaded due to the updated config of media_folder and public_folder.

https://blogs.neelamegam.in/2024-03-24-blogging-from-netlify-cms-what-a-wonder/